# how to fix 401 Unauthorized error with using retrofit in android?

Tags: android, json, retrofit, postman, retrofit2

I have used retrofit2 library in android. I am getting 401 Unauthorized error. if anyone have solved this issue so please tell me here. I learn retrofit2 use in android.
this is APIClient class.
            APIClient class :

```
           public class APIClient {
                private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
                private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .connectTimeout(7, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .readTimeout(7, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .writeTimeout(7, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .build();
                public static Retrofit getClient() {
                    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
                    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

                    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://www.example.com/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .client(okHttpClient).build();

                    return retrofit;
                }
            }
```

this is my interface.

```
                    public interface APIInterface {
                        @GET("/teacher/api/getStudentTakeAttendanceList")
                        Call<List<Apiresponse>> getstudentAttendanceListView(@Query("teacherId") int userId);

                    //    Callback<List<Apiresponse>> studentAttendanceListView(@Query("teacherId") int userId);
                    }
```

this is my final call.

```
final Call<List<Apiresponse>> getstudentAttendanceListView = apiInterface.getstudentAttendanceListView(userId);
            getstudentAttendanceListView.enqueue(new Callback<List<Apiresponse>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<Apiresponse>> call, Response<List<Apiresponse>> response) {
                        Log.d("responsecode:::", "" + response.code());

                        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }

                        Log.e("response::", "" + response.errorBody());

    //                    Log.e("response::", "" + response.body());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<Apiresponse>> call, Throwable t) {
                        call.cancel();
                        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    }
                });
in app.gradle file.
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    output.
    responsecode:::: 401
    response::: okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@537beb4c
```

Comment: you must add the token to the api in the header  , either you can save it in the sharedpreferences and use it or you can pass it as a companion objet(Kotlin) or static fields (Java) ==> the 401 error is related to the authentification not to the retrofit

Comment: @B.mansouri thanks for reply.. I want to fetch data from server using GET.

Answer (score 2):

A `401 Unauthorized error` means that you don't have the rights to access. 
In your case it means that you have to add a header with a accessToken.

[Here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header) is explained how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you should add your api access token in the request header, you should ask your api developer for the headers keys,you should also try the request first with postman

Answer (score 0):

**401 Unauthorized Retrofit**
It means you don't have the rights to access.

```css
private fun getTestData() {

        val client =  OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(BasicAuthInterceptor("username","paswword"))
            .build()
        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
         val api = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Baseurl)
      
      //use this
            .client(client)
      //to solve the problem
      
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build()
            .create(ApiInterface::class.java)
        api.getData().enqueue(object : Callback<Mytest?> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Mytest?>?, response: Response<Mytest?>?) {
                //TODO("Not yet implemented")
                val responseBody= response?.body()

                val stringBuilder=StringBuilder()

                stringBuilder.append(responseBody?.id)

        
                        Log.v("testjee",responseBody.toString())

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Mytest?>?, t: Throwable?) {
                //TODO("Not yet implemented")
                showInfo.toastShort("error"+ t?.message.toString())
                Log.d("error",t.toString())
                if (t != null) {
                    print("testjee"+t.message.toString())
                }
            }
        })

    }
```

```css
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Headers

interface ApiInterface {


    @GET("xxx/xxx")
    fun getData(): Call<Mytest>
}
```

```css
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.0'
    //implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1'

    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1"

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'


    configurations.all {
        // OkHttp 3.5.0+ includes the websockets API, so we need this to prevent a conflict
        //exclude module: 'okhttp-ws'
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    }
```

```css
import okhttp3.Credentials
import okhttp3.Interceptor


class BasicAuthInterceptor(username: String, password: String): Interceptor {
    private var credentials: String = Credentials.basic(username, password)

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): okhttp3.Response {
        var request = chain.request()
        request = request.newBuilder().header("Authorization", credentials).build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```